# Clone <select> without the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to clone a select without cloning the selected one and each time i try to clone it ,check previous select and remove selected options !

```
<select class="form-control name_list" name="idproduit1" id="idproducts1">
<option value="1">piece7</option>
<option value="3">Piece88</option>
<option value="4">Piece6</option>
<option value="5">piece99</option>
<option value="7">Produit 6</option>
```

Js :

```
$('#add').click(function(){  
     i++;
     var options = $('[name="idproduit1"] > option ').clone().find('option:selected').remove().end();
     $('#dynamic_field').append('<select class="form-control name_list" name="idproduit'+i+'"></select>');
     $('[name="idproduit'+i+'"]').append(options);

});
```

Comment: Cool..... so what is you question?

Comment: how to do it dude !

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Where is your attempt(s)? This isn't a free writing service... Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share what efforts you have put. Share your code

Comment: ok wait i will edit it

Comment: Sorry Guys first Time i ask questions ^^' !

Comment: Removing selected options is not a good choice/approach, let say from Select A(option 2 - selected), you cloned Select B(does not have option 2), later from Select A(option 3 - selected) then what about Select B(having option 3)? IMHO, disabled option would be good approach

Comment: Select A it gonna be disabled after cloning (but if disabled it not gonna be send to the server .. )

Comment: @KhalilTijani this is why it's better to disable what the client can select in the new appended options by disabling the options that have been previously selected. So I agree with **Arvind** disabling rather than removing would be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can still keep your current code (which is not shared on the post as of time of writing) and just add

```
clonedSelectEl.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Provided you have set a default placeholder option